# Why sometimes exhaustive testing is easier than pairwise testing?

Tags: testing, combinatorics

Consider a function with 4 parameters, each with 2 options = 16 combinations testing ALL possible combinations. But 24 with pairwise testing - how come? It would be hence more difficult to test pairs (which does not reveal - in context of software testing - problems caused by interaction of 3 variables) than ALL combinations.

Or the advantage is that with covering or orthogonal arrays, these pairs can be arranged so that fewer runs are needed?

Answer (score 1):

Which pairwise tool did you use? I generated a pairwise test suite using Pairwiser, an online tool for pairwise testing, and it generated 5 tests when I entered 4 parameters with two options each.

Here is the result. The five columns are the five tests and p1 to p5 are the parameters. Each parameter can be either a or b.

```
    1   2   3   4   5
p1  a   b   a   b   a
p2  a   b   a   a   b
p3  b   a   a   b   b
p4  b   b   a   a   a
```

So, for your example, pairwise testing gives less tests than exhaustive testing.